# How to enter roles to the bot for a command to access it in multiple servers?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hope you can understand the title. I'm pretty new in making a Discord bot.
So I was wondering if is it possible to add an existing role to the bot so the user that has the role will have access to the command within the Discord server?

Since my bot is active in multiple servers, the code that I did is only for a Discord server so I just add the role in the index.js so when I add the role to that user, they can access to a certain command.
But after I add the bot in some servers, it gets so messy. This is the code that I did.

```
    switch(args[0]){ // ALL COMMANDS CAN BE FOUND AT THE COMMAND FOLDER
        case 'ping':
            if((!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Residents'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Member'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Owner'))) return message.channel.send(donothavepermissions)
            bot.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
        break;
        case 'ip':
            if((!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Residents'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Owner'))) return message.channel.send(onlyforedinburghresidents)
            bot.commands.get('ip').execute(message, args);
        break;
        case 'info':
            if((!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Residents'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Member'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Discord Manager'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Owner'))) return message.channel.send(donothavepermissions)
            bot.commands.get('info').execute(message, args);
        break;
        case 'clear':
            if((!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Mayor'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Assistant'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Discord Manager'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Officer'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Secretary'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Owner'))) return message.channel.send(donothavepermissions2)
            bot.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args);
        break;
        case 'poll':
            if((!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Mayor'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Assistant'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Secretary'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Discord Manager'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Officer'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Owner'))) return message.channel.send(donothavepermissions2)
            bot.commands.get('poll').execute(message, args);
        break;
        case 'broadcast':
            if((!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Mayor'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Assistant'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Secretary'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Discord Manager'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Officer'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Owner'))) return message.channel.send(donothavepermissions2)
            bot.commands.get('broadcast').execute(message, args);
            break;
        case 'help':
            if((!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Residents'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Student'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Assistant'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Secretary'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Discord Manager'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Owner'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Members'))) return message.channel.send(donothavepermissions)
            bot.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
        break;
        case 'say':
            if((!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Mayor'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Discord Manager'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Officer'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Assistant'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Secretary'))&&(!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Owner'))) return message.channel.send(donothavepermissions2)
            bot.commands.get('say').execute(message, args);
        break;
        }
})
```

As you can see, it's very messy.
What I want is, when Discord server owners are going to add an existing role (roles on their server) to my bot without accessing the index.js, it will save it. Like the MEE6 bot.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the example of MEE6 and add it to the post? Hard to understand

Comment: You can put roles on the MEE6 dashboard (located here https://mee6.xyz/dashboard/ID/settings) then after applying it, those roles will have access to Administrator Commands of the bot. Apologies that you didn't understand what I said.

Comment: No worries, this might require a database depending on how you want to go about it, do you want the server owner to chose what role is administrator or do you want it to be based on something like the name, for example: "bot-admin-bypass" or something?

Comment: I want the server owner to chose what role is the administrator.